# Peloton Trainer - what style of cleats are used?

Tags: trainer, cleat

I was wondering what cleat standard is compatible with the Peloton Trainer ?

What cleat standard is installed in the default configuration ?

Comment: At $1995 US to buy, plus $140/year for the data subscription, OUCH.  You might consider zwift plus a trainer instead, at least from a pricing point of view.

Comment: @Criggie it was gifted to my mother, I'm getting her shoes and cleats for Christmas.

Comment: Honestly?  Bit of a poisoned chalice gift.  To use the features, you need to pay for the monthly/annual subscription.  I'm not sure if the whole unit locks out without a valid subscription or if you can still pedal.

Comment: Depending on how your mum rides, a pair of $10 platform pedals might be a better solution.

Comment: @Criggie I hear you loud and clear and it wouldn't be my choice, but it's done, and I wouldn't consider it a poisoned challis in any way. Putting money aside, of which none of mine was spent on the machine or subscription, riding something to exercise is better then not riding, yes? Riding clipless is better then not, yes? Are there more affordable trainers? Of course. I ride cheap rollers. That said, besides good shorts, which I also got her, I believe quality shoes are a befitting gift and I hope that she will eventually use them on the road. Delta is weird but not a far cry from keo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to   https://www.onepeloton.com/shop/bike

> The Peloton Bike uses LOOK Delta clip-in pedals, so you’ll need a pair of compatible cycling shoes to ride.

[image]

However the images show standard bike pedals with 9/16" standard threads.  You should be able to fit whatever pedals you like.

Comment: It makes sense to ride the same cleat system as your normal road bike, to help train the muscle memory.  On the other hand, there's no need to have cleats at all, flats and optional toe straps would make it that much less work to get on and "ride"

Comment: Delta has been obsolete for years, I wonder why they chose that one instead of something people would actually use on their bikes. On the other hand, if you're paying $2000 for an indoor trainer, why would you skimp on pedals?

Comment: @ojs guessing - you're not going to walk far if there's a trainer at home.  I suspect a trainer would appeal to roadies more than MTB?

Comment: this may be surprise to you, but many people use Look Keo and SPD-R on their bikes, some weirdos even Time or Speedplay. If you actually wanted to appeal to roadies, you'd pick one of the more common non-obsolete systems or sell the trainer without pedals like bikes are sold.

Comment: @ojs no that's not a surprise.  For $2k it should come with multifunction pedals with platforms around both side, and both sides support a cleat as well, for added versatility.

Comment: @ojs there's a chance it can be customised on ordering too, to include the pedals you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Actually, *IT DEPENDS***. Peloton sells a home version that uses LOOK and a commercial version (to most hotels and apartment buildings) that cannot use a LOOK but that have a shoe-cage on one side and an SPD SH51 clip on the other side. Most Peloton reps do not seem to know this (for all the money they charge you think the company would train its people...) so check your bike carefully. It might be easier to take a picture of the bike pedal and bring it to the bike store so you don't accidentally buy the wrong clips--or shoes. (Not all shoes take SPD and LOOK, many only take one type or the other.)